# Cannot find iis management tool on vista home basic

Tags: iis-7, windows-vista

I am running windows vista home basic service pack 2.
I tried to install iis on my laptop.
But I cannot find **IIS Management Console** to select to install.

Once I try to access **localhost** from my browser it gives me 404 error.

```
The resource you are looking for does not have a handler associated with it.
```

Please advice me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I faced to the same situation when I had to install it on Windows XP. Compare to the previous version of IIS, it isn't so obvious. Try http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770472%28v=ws.10%29.aspx .

Comment: To get **IIS Management Console** to there we need to install it from add/remove windows feature. But I cannot find it from there.

Comment: Can you do https://support.appliedi.net/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/663/0/iis7-management-console-install--configure ?